# How to deploy an app the right way in ArgoCD via CLI?

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I installed ArgoCD in the kubernetes cluster and configure CLI.

When I create an application via UI — the application success deployed, when I try to deploy the application everything is running successfully. When I import YAMML and try to deploy the same application via CLI - **nothing happens**.

**applicaition.yml:**

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: hashicorp-vault
  finalizers:
    - resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io
spec:
  project: infra
  source:
    repoURL: "https://helm.releases.hashicorp.com"
    targetRevision: 0.23.0
    helm:
      values: |
        ui:
          enabled: true
        injector:
          enabled: false
        server:
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: 512Mi
              cpu: 250m
            limits:
              memory: 512Mi
              cpu: 250m
    chart: vault
  destination:
    server: "https://kubernetes.default.svc"
    namespace: vault
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: true
      selfHeal: true
```

**Apply:**

```
> kubectl apply -f application.yaml

application.argoproj.io/hashicorp-vault created
```

**Check via argocd cli:**

```
> argocd app list

NAME  CLUSTER  NAMESPACE  PROJECT  STATUS  HEALTH  SYNCPOLICY  CONDITIONS  REPO  PATH  TARGET
— empty —
```

**Check via kubectl:**

```
> kubectl get application

NAME                   SYNC STATUS   HEALTH STATUS
hashicorp-vault
```

There is also nothing in the UI, there is no information in the logs either.
When I create an application through the interface, through CLI it is visible successfully.